# Kartograph - AttributeError: _Shape instance has no attribute 'parts'

Tags: python, shapefile, svg

I am new to GIS and open source tools so bear with me.

I am attempting to convert a shapefile to svg by running kartograph as a python module.  My source file (provided by the local GIS Administration) contains nearly 50,000 parcels of land and I only want to carry over a single attribute for each parcel (which I will use for colorizing later). Here is my code:

```
from kartograph import Kartograph
K = Kartograph()

config = {
    "layers": {
        "county": { 
            "src": "parcels.shp",
            "attributes": {
                    "id": "XXDSDS"
            }
        }
    },
}

K.generate(config, outfile='test-file.svg')
```

The following error results:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 19, in 
>       K.generate(config, outfile='test-file.svg')
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/kartograph.py", line 46, in generate
>       _map = Map(opts, self.layerCache, format=format)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 48, in **init**
>       me.proj = me._init_projection()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 88, in _init_projection
>       map_center = self.__get_map_center()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 140, in __get_map_center
>       features = self._get_bounding_geometry()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 257, in _get_bounding_geometry
>       charset=layer.options['charset']
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/layersource/shplayer.py", line 121, in get_features
>       geom = shape2geometry(shp, ignore_holes=ignore_holes, min_area=min_area, bbox=bbox, proj=self.proj)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/layersource/shplayer.py", line 153, in shape2geometry
>       geom = shape2polygon(shp, ignore_holes=ignore_holes, min_area=min_area, proj=proj)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/layersource/shplayer.py", line 170, in shape2polygon
>       parts = shp.parts[:]
>   AttributeError: _Shape instance has no attribute 'parts'

I have run the code using a different source file (U.S. county map) and the conversion worked, so I don't think there are any code or version problems.  I assume kartograph is looking for something in my source file that it can't find or doesn't exist.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot the AttributeError?

If it matters, I'm working on a Mac 10.9.5

UPDATE: following gene's guidance in the comments, I attempted to read my shapefile using pyshp (shapefile).  shapefile appears to read the source file just fine and appears to recognize the 'parts' attribute. Here is an example of my work:

```
>>> import shapefile
>>> sf = shapefile.Reader("TaxParcels.shp")
>>> shapes = sf.shapes()
>>> len(shapes)
70073
>>> for name in dir(shapes[45873]):
...     if not name.startswith('__'):
...             name
... 
'bbox'
'parts'
'points'
'shapeType'
>>> shapes[876].shapeType
5
>>> shapes[876].parts
[0]
>>> fields = sf.fields
>>> len(fields)
206
>>> len(sf.records())
70073
>>>
```

I don't have enough experience yet to know what the next step is in troubleshooting.  I even tried stripping the "attributes" parameter from my script and I came up with the same error.  Could the problem be with how Kartograph is handling the shapefile?

Comment: Why you don't use the Apple Python ?

Comment: The error is `_Shape instance has no attribute 'parts'` and it comes from [Pyshp](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/wiki/PyShpDocs) and not kartograph. Try to open your shapefile with Pyshp (shapefile)

Comment: @gene thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I am in the process of trying to open my shp file in pyshp (currently iterating shapes).  I will try to reproduce the attributeerror and follow-up.  My shp has 70073 shapes so it could take a while. and btw, I am using the native python on my mac.

Comment: updated original post